# Replicating MySQL Database programmatically with Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, replication

I want to replicate two mysql databases, I know how to do that.
The problem is these two servers aren't connected to each other. they connect at certain times and then doing replication then disconnect again.
I want to run `slave start;` and `slave stop;` programmatically ! with Qt.
I can run the mysql terminal command but I want to know when replication finished. To disconnect servers.

Comment: What exactly have you tried yourself?

Comment: Please rewrite your question, and express yourself with clarity.